# Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog() is not working in Metro App?

Tags: html, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2012, winjs

Iam trying to print an alert in my metro application,but it is not working?Here iam using visual studio2012(HTML,WinJS) and windows8RC for developing the application.Can anyone suggest me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you provide your code?
This works for me:

```
Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Content", "Title").showAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless it is a seriouse error I would recommend using a FlyOut:

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Define a flyout in HTML as you wish -->
<div id="informationFlyout" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Flyout">
    <p>
        Some informative text
    </p>
</div>

<!-- an anchor for the flyout, where it should be displayed -->
<div id="flyoutAnchor"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
    // Get an anchor for the flyout
    var flyoutAnchor = document.getElementById("flyoutAnchor"); 

    // Show flyout at anchor
    document.getElementById("informationFlyout").winControl.show(flyoutAnchor);
```

To dismiss the flyout after a set amount of time you could just do a setTimeout and hide in you're code:

```
// execute this code after 2000ms
setTimeout(function () {

    // Fetch the flyout
    var flyout = document.getElementById("informationFlyout"); // Get the flyout from HTML

    // Check if the element still exists in DOM
    if (flyout) 
        flyout.winControl.hide(); // Dismiss the flyout

}, 2000);
```

Read more about the FlyOut-popups [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211726.aspx)